# Does Opera (Presto engine version) have a bookmarks toolbar?

Tags: bookmarks, opera, toolbar

I'm using Opera (Presto engine version), and I want a simple toolbar for often used bookmarks like how Firefox has it.

I know that there's "Speed Dial", but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Is there a feature built into the Opera browser where I can quickly and or easily access bookmarks without being limited to the Speed Dial page or having to go into bookmarks manager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right mouse button on the interface -> Appearance -> check "Personal Bar"

**Edit** : more simple way : menu "View" -> Toolbars -> "Personal Bar"

You can find more details about this toolbar on [this page](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.00/en/toolbars.html). Note though that if you can easily move things to this toolbar, it is not a "folder" from your bookmarks, like in Firefox. Items added there are added to your bookmarks, but if you remove them from the Personal Bar, they will remain in your bookmarks.

Comment: outdated answer

Answer (score 3):

In Opera you can use bookmarks from the side bar which is provided by default. I feel it's much easier and as convenient as the Firefox bookmarks toolbar as you can see here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned Opera's bookmark toolbar is called the Personal Bar. Bookmarks can be dragged there, and will accept both bookmarks and bookmark folders. You can add a bookmark to the personal bar using the bookmark item properties dialog too:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 ways to do this.

1. Go to view toolbars and check personal bar. Then you can drag bookmarks and bookmark folders to this.
2. Open up the panels and select bookmarks. (ctrl + B) does this. This will give you a side bar with all your bookmarks listed.
3. Yet another way without using the huge bookmark bar is to add the bookmarks button next to your back button. First Right click on the address bar > customize > appearance > buttons > Browser and drag out the bookmarks button. I have placed mine here because I hide the menu bar and this makes it easy to get to the bookmarks.